# Limits problem - looking to understand how to answer the question.

Tags: calculus, limits

If 
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x) \neq \lim_{x\to c^+}f(x),
$$
then what can you conclude about $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$?

Is $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = f(c)$? Why or why not?

If $f$ is undefined at $x=c$, then can you conclude that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ does not exist? Explain.

Comment: Well, do you have any idea of how to answer any of the parts? Any hunches about the answers?

Comment: I understand that I can conclude that the limit of f as x approaches c does not exist. However not sure on how to understand the second and third part of this question. 'f of c' What is f of c

Comment: $f(c)$ is simply the value of $f$ at the point $x=c$.

Comment: How would I know if f would always equal $$f©$$… My brain can't even conjure up any type of solution or feedback regarding this question.

Comment: Check my answer below. I give an example there.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, $f(c)$ is the value of the function at $c$. Consider the function $f(x) = 0$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 1$. What is the limit as $x \to 0$? And what is the value of the function at $x = 0$?

For part three, consider the function $f(x) = 0$ if $x \neq 0$. This is a function which is undefined at $x = 0$. What about the limit as $x \to 0$?

Comment: For the second part. The limit as $x \to 0$ is 1. The value of the function at $x = 0$ is not equal to 0 right?

Comment: Is the limit of $f$ always equal to $f(c)$… hmmmm I have no clue then PLEASE HELP

Comment: I understand math is really easy for you guys but just please a little more insight am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: @user161304 That's hard to say. What direction are you thinking in? What part of my answer don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

1) If the one sided limits are not equivalent to each other that means that a normal limit does not exist.

2)Consider #1 and conclude the answer.

3)Hint: Consider $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{x}$

Comment: The limit does not exist in the first part of the question. So I would say that the limit of $f$ as x approaches c is not always equal to $f(c)$ right?

Comment: Is the limit of $f$ always equal to $f(c)$… hmmmm I have no clue then PLEASE HELP